# How to make Blogger show the last modified date of any post?

Tags: google, blogger, blog

How can I make Blogger show the last modified date of a post?

When I edit an old post in Blogger, is there anyway to list the last modified date somewhere? anywhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the best tutorial I've found for your question: http://www.southernspeakers.net/2010/12/show-date-for-each-blogger-post.html

In short, you have to use your Timestamp as your Date Header

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. The question clearly states he is editing an old post. All this will do is show the original date.

Answer (score 1):

You Could use following, however it changes date of publisihng an article. Set it to Current Date. Steps -

> Click on post which you want to edit in **blogger POST tab**.
>
> At **POST SETTING**, Click on Published on , then select  **Set date and time**
>
> Select **Date and Time** from **Calender** Below.
>
> And click on **DONE** and then **UPDATE**.

Preview of POST SETTING
[image: Preview of ***POST SETTING***]

Comment: That's dreadful.

Answer (score 1):

It is a good question and the very simple answer is: you cannot. Blogger does not support a last modified header.

[This page](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/47270) lists all the data points available for parsing and you will soon find that the dating options are limited. It simply isn't possible.

If you are wanting to add the relevant markup to appease the [Structured Data Tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/) then you can tell it to use the original post date by adding or editing the template:

```
<abbr class='published' expr:content='data:post.timestampISO8601' itemprop='datePublished dateModified'><data:post.timestamp/></abbr>
```

The exact code you want to use depends on how your template is laid out. The above [works](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool?url=http%253A%252F%252Fkennystechtalk.blogspot.co.uk%252F2016%252F02%252Fnew-frontiers-in-communication-systems.html) for me.

Alternatively you can add the data manually when you are editing the post. You'll need to use the HTML editor and add a relevant element. It's up to you whether you want it to show on the page or not.

```
Last updated: <div content='CCYYMMDDTHHMMSSZ' itemprop='dateModified'>March 2016</div>
```

or

```
<meta content='CCYYMMDDTHHMMSSZ' itemprop='dateModified'/>
```

I prefer the latter but you'll see some bloggers do make their modified time visible. Depends on the nature of your blog and personal preference.