# How to put last modified date in blog post on Blogger?

Tags: blogger

I want to have last modified date on my blog post on Blogger.com. I have tried [this post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/16955/how-to-make-blogger-show-the-last-modified-date-of-any-post) but it didn't work out since this solution is for the old Blogger.com

**Edit-1:**
I got to know about this meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="last-modified" content="YYYY-MM-DD@hh:mm:ss TMZ" />
```

But I don't know where to put this meta tag in specific post and how it works ?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/16955/how-to-make-blogger-show-the-last-modified-date-of-any-post

Comment: I have already tried this link. Check the question I have included this link.

Answer (score 2):

It is a good question and the very simple answer is: you cannot. Blogger does not support a last modified header.

[This page](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/47270) lists all the data points available for parsing and you will soon find that the dating options are limited. It simply isn't possible.

If you are wanting to add the relevant markup to appease the [Structured Data Tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/) then you can tell it to use the original post date by adding or editing the template:

```
<abbr class='published' expr:content='data:post.timestampISO8601' itemprop='datePublished dateModified'><data:post.timestamp/></abbr>
```

The exact code you want to use depends on how your template is laid out. The above [works](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool?url=http%253A%252F%252Fkennystechtalk.blogspot.co.uk%252F2016%252F02%252Fnew-frontiers-in-communication-systems.html) for me.

In your specific case, if you wish to use a `<meta>` tag then you'll want to use:

```
<meta http-equiv="last-modified" expr:content="data:post.timestampISO8601" />
```

Alternatively you can add the data manually when you are editing the post. You'll need to use the HTML editor and add a relevant element. It's up to you whether you want it to show on the page or not.

```
Last updated: <div content='CCYYMMDDTHHMMSSZ' itemprop='dateModified'>March 2016</div>
```

or

```
<meta content='CCYYMMDDTHHMMSSZ' itemprop='dateModified'/>
```

I prefer the latter but you'll see some bloggers do make their modified time visible. Depends on the nature of your blog and personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

As JavaScript slows down the page, it is better to use pure XHTML data variable for date time stamp, available in Blogger. I searched a lot on web, and was able to find 6 types of date variables, associated with any post. However, there can be more. These are :

For **datePublished** schema property :

1. `<data:post.date/>` 2020-06-04
2. `<data:post.dateHeader/>` 2020-06-04
3. `<data:post.timestampISO8601/>` 2020-06-04T02:18:00+05:30
4. `<data:post.date.iso8601/>` 2020-06-04T02:18:00+05:30
5. `<data:post.timestamp/>` June 04, 2020

For **dateModified** schema property :

1. `<data:post.lastUpdatedISO8601/>` 2020-06-05T20:40:40Z

Further, these dates can be formatted, as per decoration needs, using EVAL in Blogger :

```
<b:eval expr='format(data:post.date, "EEEE, d MMM YYYY")'/>
```

or

```
<b:eval expr='data:post.date format "MMM dd" ' />
```

However, This expression only works on `<data:post.date/>` and not on other 5 date variables.

The date formats should be created with ISO 8601 by following these rules :
**YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD** (eg 1997-07-16T19:20:30.45+01:00) - *Complete date plus hours, minutes, seconds and a decimal fraction of a second*, where:

- YYYY = four-digit year
- MM   = two-digit month (01=January, etc.)
- DD   = two-digit day of month (01 through 31)
- hh   = two digits of hour (00 through 23) (am/pm NOT allowed)
- mm   = two digits of minute (00 through 59)
- ss   = two digits of second (00 through 59)
- s    = one or more digits representing a decimal fraction of a second
- TZD  = time zone designator (Z or +hh:mm or -hh:mm)

https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime

I have implemented both datePublished and dateModified as following :

```
<p>Published on: <time expr:datetime='data:post.timestampISO8601' property='datePublished'><data:post.dateHeader/></time> Updated on: <time expr:datetime='data:post.lastUpdatedISO8601' property='dateModified'><data:post.lastUpdatedISO8601/></time></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the new blogger

GOTO -> LAYOUT -> BLOG POST -> below right corner click EDIT

from pop up choose date (first field) in post page options -> Save , Thats it!

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering the question.
I have already tried this. It puts the publishing date not the last modified date.

Comment: For that u need to visit the post and change the publishing date on the right side..